# kill remote process by ssh

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I can't directly access target host, need ssh as a proxy.

How can I kill a process from local use ssh ? I try this:

```
ssh root@$center "ssh root@$ip \"ps -ef|grep -v grep|grep $target_dir/$main|awk '{print \$2}'|xargs kill\""
```

it got error:

```
kill: can't find process "root"
```

And how to avoid error where process not exist ?

Comment: what's wrong with what you have tried ? Are you getting an error or something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`pkill -f`](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=pkill+-f+%22%24target_dir%2F%24main%22) to easily kill a process by matching its command-line.

```
ssh root@$center ssh root@$ip pkill -f "$target_dir/$main"
```

Answer (score 16):

Suppose your process' name is `name`, then you can try something like this:

```
ssh hostname "pid=\$(ps aux | grep 'name' | awk '{print \$2}' | head -1); echo \$pid |xargs kill"
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer worked for me. Just to point out that there is a typo at the end of the line where you don't need to scape the last '"' character. So replacing "... kill\" to "... kill" did for me.